# On first mount of app, Drawer buttons are clickable even when its closed for some time

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

Current Behavior

React Navigation 5

If user Taps on screen just after he opens app, buttons of Drawer screens are clicked even when drawer is closed.

This is for atleat 2 - 3 seconds after app is first mounted.

Comment: That would be very good if you add some kind of a screen record as a gif or video to understand the problem better.

Comment: and a snippet or your code